# Powershell move to folder in the same directory

Tags: powershell, file, automation, directory

I have 20000 more folders under Z:\testfolder, it's a network mapped drive.
I need to find all the folders with specific name like "01-Jan","02-Feb","03-Mar","04-Apr","05-May","06-Jun","07-Jul","08-Aug","09-Sep","10-Oct","11-Dec","12-Dec", and move these folders to the folder "2022" under the same directory.
All folders are empty folders.
The folder "2022" needs to be created.

I already created the 2022 folder using the following command under a directory with these files:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\testfolder -Filter 01-Jan -Directory -Recurse -Exclude 2020 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | Copy-Item -Destination {$($_.Fullname) -replace '01-Jan',"2022"}
```

But I don't know how to move the folder to the current folder.

Current Tree:

```
Z:.
├───A
│   ├───01-JAN
│   ├───02-Feb
│   ├───03-Mar
│   ├───04-Apr
│   ├───05-May
│   ├───06-Jun
│   ├───07-Jul
│   ├───08-Aug
│   ├───09-Sep
│   ├───10-Oct
│   ├───11-Nov
│   └───12-Dec
├───B
│   └───D
│       ├───01-JAN
│       ├───02-Feb
│       ├───03-Mar
│       ├───04-Apr
│       ├───05-May
│       ├───06-Jun
│       ├───07-Jul
│       ├───08-Aug
│       ├───09-Sep
│       ├───10-Oct
│       ├───11-Nov
│       └───12-Dec
└───C
    ├───01-JAN
    ├───02-Feb
    ├───03-Mar
    ├───04-Apr
    ├───05-May
    ├───06-Jun
    ├───07-Jul
    ├───08-Aug
    ├───09-Sep
    ├───10-Oct
    ├───11-Nov
    └───12-Dec
```

The expected effect:

```
Z:.
├───A
│   └───2022
│       ├───01-Jan
│       ├───02-Feb
│       ├───03-Mar
│       ├───04-Apr
│       ├───05-May
│       ├───06-Jun
│       ├───07-Jul
│       ├───08-Aug
│       ├───09-Sep
│       ├───10-Oct
│       ├───11-Nov
│       └───12-Dec
├───B
│   └───D
│       └───2022
│           ├───01-Jan
│           ├───02-Feb
│           ├───03-Mar
│           ├───04-Apr
│           ├───05-May
│           ├───06-Jun
│           ├───07-Jul
│           ├───08-Aug
│           ├───09-Sep
│           ├───10-Oct
│           ├───11-Nov
│           └───12-Dec
└───C
    └───2022
        ├───01-Jan
        ├───02-Feb
        ├───03-Mar
        ├───04-Apr
        ├───05-May
        ├───06-Jun
        ├───07-Jul
        ├───08-Aug
        ├───09-Sep
        ├───10-Oct
        ├───11-Nov
        └───12-Dec
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but may be in the correct, general direction. The `2020` directory is created if it does not exist. When you are confident that the directory will be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` command.

```
$DirNames = @('01-jan', '02-feb', '03-mar','04-apr', '05-may', '06-jun',
    '07-jul', ' 08-aug', '09-sep', '10-oct', '11-nov', '12-dec')
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Path 'Z:\' |
    Where-Object { $DirNames -contains $_.Name } |
    ForEach-Object {
        $NewDir = Join-Path -Path $_.Directory -ChildPath '2020'
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $NewDir)) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewDir | Out-Null
        }
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $NewDir -WhatIf
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$folderNames = 1..12 | ForEach-Object { "$('{0:d2}' -f $_)-$([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName($_))" }
Get-ChildItem -Path 'Z:\testfolder' -Recurse | Where-Object BaseName -In $folderNames | Group-Object -Property Parent | ForEach-Object {
    $dir2022 = Join-Path -Path $_.Name -ChildPath '2022'
    New-Item -Path $dir2022 -ItemType Directory
    foreach ($dir in $_.Group) {
        Move-Item -Path $dir.FullName -Destination $dir2022
    }
}
```

`$folderNames` will contain only the names `01-Jan...12-Dec`. First, we get all the directories recursively in `Z:\testfolder` then we select only the folders that match the `$folderNames`. We then group them by their parent such that we retain the structure `B\D` for example. We then iterate the groups and create a `2022` directory `B\D\2022`. Finally, for each member in the group, we will move them in the `2022` dir (i.e. `B\D\01-Jan` to `B\D\2022\01-Jan`).